# Abrir um Flexdashboard em outra aba do navegador com "runtime:shiny" através de um Actionbutton em um aplicativo shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rmarkdown

Tenho um aplicativo shiny da seguinte estrutura, onde o código a seguir é denominado `app.R`

```
    library(shiny)


    ui <- fluidPage(

        theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
        navbarPage(title = "Teste ",
               tabPanel("Renderizar Rmarkdown em outra aba",

                            actionButton("teste", "Teste app dentro app"))
    ))

    server <- function(input, output) {
           observeEvent(input$teste, {
         rmarkdown::run ("arquivo.Rmd")
         })
}
```

Dentro do Shiny há a execução de um flexdashboard, via `rmarkdown :: run`, pois o flexdashboard contem o parâmetro `runtime:shiny`

onde o que foi denominado `arquivo.Rmd`, tem a seguinte estrutura

````
---
title: "Gene Expression Biclustering"
author: "Bryan Lewis"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
library(biclust)
data(BicatYeast)
set.seed(1)
res <- biclust(BicatYeast, method=BCPlaid(), verbose=FALSE)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
 selectInput("clusterNum", label = h3("Cluster number"), 
    choices = list("1" = 1, "2" = 2, "3" = 3, "4" = 4, "5" = 5), 
    selected = 1)
```

Microarray data matrix for 80 experiments with Saccharomyces Cerevisiae
organism extracted from R's `biclust` package.

Sebastian Kaiser, Rodrigo Santamaria, Tatsiana Khamiakova, Martin Sill, Roberto
  Theron, Luis Quintales, Friedrich Leisch and Ewoud De Troyer. (2015). biclust:
  BiCluster Algorithms. R package version 1.2.0.
  http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=biclust

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Heatmap

```{r}

num <- reactive(as.integer(input$clusterNum))

col = colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "darkblue"), space="Lab")(10)
renderPlot({
    p = par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
    heatmapBC(BicatYeast, res, number=num(), xlab="", ylab="",
      order=TRUE, useRaster=TRUE, col=col)
    par(p)
})
```


Row {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Parallel Coordinates

```{r}
renderPlot(
  parallelCoordinates(BicatYeast, res, number=num())
)
```

### Data for Selected Cluster

```{r}
# only display table for values in cluster 4
renderTable(
  BicatYeast[which(res@RowxNumber[, num()]), which(res@NumberxCol[num(), ])]
)
```
````

Criei outro código, com os dados a seguir, onde fiz um .bat para ele, e um atalho no meu desktop, e ao clicar no atalho , o app abre diretamente no chrome

```
library(shiny)
runApp("C:\\Users\\holiveira\\Desktop\\trabalhando\\teste", launch.browser = TRUE)
```

O grande problema é que não consegui fazer um `Shiny` executar um `.Rmd` com `runtime: shiny`

Gostaria de uma solução para que meu actionbutton do shinyapp executasse em outra aba do navegador esse flexdashboard

Comment: Tente colocar `runtime: shiny` acima de `output` no cabeçalho `YAML`.

Comment: Não funcionou, aparentemente há uma limitação de executar um Shiny dentro de outro Shiny, pensei em tentar via código executar através de outra sessão, mas ainda não consegui.

Uma saída é subir vários shiny para o shinyapps.io, e criar uma tela de botões que direciona ao link dos shinys, mas isso seria muito dispendioso, se conseguisse executar direto seria o ideal

Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: Can't call `runApp()` from within `runApp()`. If your application code contains `runApp()`, please remove it.